# Plotting an evolutionary algorithm's search space

Tags: matlab, search, plot, genetic-algorithm, mathematical-optimization

I am working on discrete optimization problem and I want to plot the search space. Actually I would like to see mutation and crossover operations visually in the search space. I haven't got any idea on that!

Can someone tell me how to plot search space for a discrete optimization problem for Genetic Algorithm in MATLAB?

- I don't use any toolbox.
- An example for such an optimization problem is traveling salesman.

Comment: What kind of plot do you want? I don't see any practical possibility.

Comment: I think the suggested answer below will work for me, Actually I need an approach which summarizes n-dimensional space into two dimensional space (1 dimension for generation number and the other for chromosome ).

Comment: @Ray, thank you for editing my post, sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult since, obviously, GAs search high-dimensional spaces.

You might try [Chernoff faces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_face) but I've never been fond of them.

One visualization that I've tried is to track the metric entropy of genes across the population. If you map that value (which ranges from 0..1) into a color-range, you can visualize the entropy of the entire population as a row of colored boxes (one for each gene). Put the next generation's row immediately below (or above) that, making your Y axis represent time.

The resulting image visually shows the areas of rapid convergence (metric entropy going towards 0) versus the areas where the search took more time and does, I think, deliver at least a small amount of value into the dynamics of the search.

Comment: thank you so much, it seems be a practical approach, but I haven't any information about metric entropy o genes, can you briefly explain it for me?

Comment: The metric entropy is the Shannon entropy divided by the length of the string. http://www.shannonentropy.netmark.pl/ In GAs, the entropy of each gene across the population is *extremely* useful, as a low entropy means that the population has converged (for a particular gene) while an entropy near 1 means that the GA is searching broadly across that hyperplane.